# How to set variables in Dremio

Tags: sql, dremio

How do you set a variable in dremio?

In sql, normally you can do something like:

```
SET @ID = (SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 1)
```

or

```
SELECT @ID = (SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 1)
```

This does not seem to work for Dremio query.  Anybody know how variables work in dremio?

Comment: reading the dremio documentations , you can't 'declare` variables. so seems like you can't do this

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. We can't set variables in Dremio.

Dremio uses ANSI SQL where there is no such construct.